# drawString with Rectangle border

Tags: java, graphics

I want to draw string using Graphics with Rectangle border outside the string.

This is what I already do:

```
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        String str = "aString Test";

        int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(str);
        int height = fontMetrics.getHeight();

        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;

        // Draw String
        g2d.drawString(str, x, y);
        // Draw Rectangle Border based on the string length & width
        g2d.drawRect(x - 2, y - height + 2, width + 4, height);
    }
```

My problem is, **I want to draw string with new line ("\n") with Rectangle border outside**:

This is the code for the new line:

```
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        FontMetrics fontMetrics = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        String str = "aString\nTest";

        int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(str);
        int height = fontMetrics.getHeight();

        int x = 100;
        int y = 100;

        // Drawing string per line
        for (String line : str.split("\n")) {
            g2d.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me for this problem? I appreciate your help & suggestion...

**Final Code**

```
        int numberOfLines = 0;

        for (String line : str.split("\n")) {
            if(numberOfLines == 0)
                g2d.drawString(line, x, y);
            else
                g2d.drawString(line, x, y += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
            numberOfLines++;
        }

        g2d.drawRect(x - 2, y - height * numberOfLines + 2, width + 4, height * numberOfLines);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your issues is with the rectangle's height.

Try keeping a record of how many lines you have eg:

```
int numberOfLines=0;

for (String line : str.split("\n")) {
    g2d.drawString(line, x , y + (numberOfLines * height));
    numberOfLines++;
}

g2d.drawRect(x - 2, y - height + 2, width + 4, height * numberOfLines);
```

This also changes how it works out the y value for drawing the string.

Would something like that work?

Comment: It works, I made some changes for the height:

g2d.drawRect(x - 2, y - height * numberOfLines + 2, width + 4, height * numberOfLines);

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a regular JLabel object, and then set its text with html and include a 
 tag. e.g. `myLabel.setText("<html>aString<br>Test</html>");`, then add a border with a single line to the JLabel.